# How do I install w32codecs by hand?

Tags: installation, package-management, codecs

Have searched the internet but the guy does not explain in detail so I decided to post my question here I hope someone can help me.

Note: Package I am trying to install is the w32codecs, I await the answer.

Comment: This is an English-speaking site, please write your question in English. But if I guess your question right, don't do it this way; instead, read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi cara, vc não precisa instalar o ".tar.gz", pode instalar o pacote usando `apt-get`, o programa `w32codecs` esta no repositorio multimedia do Ubuntu.

Na terminal:

```
$ sudo wget http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
$ sudo apt-get -q update
$ sudo apt-get --yes -q --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring
$ sudo apt-get -q update
$ sudo apt-get --yes install app-install-data-medibuntu apport-hooks-medibuntu
$ sudo apt-get install w32codecs libdvdcss2
```

Si vc tiver alguma duvida, pode fazer suas perguntas no canal do ubuntu brasileiro, #ubuntu-br no freenode.net

Boa tarde

**Possible transltaion:** Hi dude, you need not install "Tar.gz", you can install the package using `apt-get`, the 'w32codecs' in multimedia repository of Ubuntu.

In the terminal:

- See above code *

If you have any questions, you can ask your questions in the channel of the Brazilian ubuntu, # ubuntu on freenode.net

good afternoon

Comment: Obrigado! pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

The "tar.gz" file is a compressed file like "zip". You can extract by right clicking over it and selecting "Extract Here":

[image]